# uWSGI server sometimes hung up for unknown reasons

Tags: django, uwsgi

I've operated Django + uWSGI apps for a year on AWS, and it was working well until two weeks ago, but I run into the problem that **the specific uWSGI process sometimes hung up and rarely recover automatically.** I've monitored uWSGI processes via *uwsgitop*, by the way.

Strangely enough, I'm always running three uWSGI servers on the same EC2 instance, but only the specific (most accessed) app's process always hung up, and the rest two uWSGI processes will never hung up and can respond to HTTP requests even during the error. Even though they work on the same hardware and network, and are connected to same MySQL/Redis server.

That uWSGI process were dumping the following "OSError: write error" message during it was stuck, (but I don't think this message is useful information.)

```
Sat Aug 17 15:44:30 2019 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during POST /XXXX(172.XXX.XXX)
OSError: write error
[pid: 2131|app: 0|req: 921/7007] 172.XXX.XXX.XXX () {62 vars in 1416 bytes} [Sat Aug 17 15:44:30 2019] POST /XXXX => generated 0 bytes in 28 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

and the Django were dumping the following *Connection timed out* error.

```
2019/08/17 15:43:32 [error] 2265#0: *13198 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.XXX.XX.XXX, server: xxx.xx, request: "POST /xxx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/www/xxx/django.sock", host: "xxx.xx", referrer: "https://xxx.xx/xxx"
```

I never changed the configuration of the server and application code in the meanwhile.

## Incomplete workaround I did

I checked the CPU/memory usage and the disk space during the error, but:

- the load average was very low (0.2)
- the memory seemed to have enough free space (total 3.8GB/ used 2.1GB)
- and the disk space also have enough capacity (total 200GB/ used 16GB).

Next, I searched for a solution and found that too many MySQL connections sometimes cause such an error. And then I checked the number of TIME_WAIT 
 connections,

```
netstat -anp| grep TIME_WAIT | wc
```

and finally **I upgraded the instance type of RDS from *db.t2.medium* to *db.t2.large*,** then the error seemed settle down and the uWSGI server started to respond to HTTP requests. That was a week ago.

To tell the truth, I didn't know why and how this upgrade improved the uWSGI stuck.

**However, the uWSGI server hung up again today.** Note that the number of HTTP requests and CPU/memory usage is even lower than the previous situation.

## I want to know:

- Why my uWSGI server hung up on a whim?
- Is there what I can do / what I have to do to improve this situation?

I have no idea for investigating and solving the problem anymore.